# If $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is in ${d(\frac{u}{v})}$ form, can we express it is as ${d({u}{v}^{-1})}$, and solve using Product Rule of Differentiation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

If we have $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in the form ${d(\frac{u}{v})}$, can we convert it to ${d({u}{v^{-1}})}$ and use Multiplication Rule on it, instead of Division Rule (which is longer, and cumbersome) for bigger expressions?

PS. I am new to MathJax, so forgive me if I have made any mistakes with the code

Comment: Yes, of course. Not sure it'll actually be less cumbersome though.

Comment: In fact, when you learned the division rule, surely you had to prove it using the multiplication rule and inverse rule?

Comment: The usual quotient rule $d(u/v) = (v du - u dv)/v^2$ is equivalently $v^{-1}du - u v^{-2}dv$, and you can see how it follows immediately from applying the product rule to $u v^{-1}$.